# Is there a way to use the folder name as default resolver (instead index.js) filename when import or require?

Tags: node.js

As in the node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules):

> If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then
> Node.js will attempt to load an index.js or index.node file out of
> that directory. For example, if there was no package.json file in the
> above example, then require('./some-library') would attempt to load:
>
> ./some-library/index.js
>
> ./some-library/index.node

So when we give the directory without the filename it looks automatically to index.js and index.node. Is there a way to look first for the name of the folder for the file? For instance:

I have a module in **"Afolder/"** directory, with the name **Afolder.js** and I use:

```
import module from 'Afolder';
```

Here what I want is that node automatically looks first for **Afolder.js** and then for index.js and index.node .

Comment: why not `import module from 'Afolder/Afolder.js';`?

Comment: @pedromss Once I asked the same for index.js, why dont they just use Afolder/index.js. Using it alot brings this question to mind. Actually right now I am using it the way you described ('Afolder/Afolder.js') , just looking if there is a way.

Comment: If there is a convention around `index.js` that using it explicitly may be considered clutter. If the computer already looks for an `index.js` why should I tell it to look for an `index.js`? However if it doesn't know that it must look for `Afolder.js` then I must tell him (yes him, not it :P) sounds pretty reasonable to me. Don't know if there is another way